# Why a div and body didn't get the mousemove event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am registering `mousemove` handlers in

http://jsfiddle.net/cbsub/2/  as tried on Chrome and Firefox.

Part of the code is:

```
$("body").on("mousemove", function () {
    console.log("$('body') mousemove listener invoked");
});

$("#foo").on("mousemove", function () {
    console.log("$('#foo') mousemove listener invoked");
});
```

but for some reason, they never get called, but the `html`, `document`, and `window` handlers for `mousemove` are called.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have the scripts wrapped in head and the statement.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

returns undefined and your script breaks so no event handler attachment code beyond that executes.

Wrap them in window.onload or document ready and it will work fine.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ErVJU/)**

Since the scripts are wrapped in the head while it executes the document has not been loaded and it won't be able to find the element to bind the handler to. jquery will not return `undefined` if element is not found so it doesn't break the script where as document function of native js element return undefined if the element is not found. *Only thing that doesn't need to be in `document.ready` or present after the element in DOM is `document` which is available even before the document is ready.*

```
$(function () { //document.ready
    $(window).on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("window mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    $(document).on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("document mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    $(document.documentElement).on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("document.documentElement mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("document.body mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    $("body").on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("$('body') mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    $("#foo").on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("$('#foo') mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    $("#foo").mousemove(function () {
        console.log("$('#foo') mousemove listener invoked");
    });

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onmousemove = function () {
        console.log("DOM level 0 body mousemove listener invoked");
    };

    document.getElementById("foo").onmousemove = function () {
        console.log("DOM level 0 foo mousemove listener invoked");
    };
});
```

Comment: hm... good explanation.  one minor thing is I don't see an error reported in Chrome's developer tool saying that there is no property `onmousemove` for `undefined`.  If, after the page loaded, and I type intentionally `document.getElementsByTagName("foobarwahlah")[0].onmousemove = function () {}` then it will say `TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmousemove' of undefined`

Comment: I see that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmousemove' of undefined ` However your issue could be the timing. If you place them under the ready or after the elements in the html(end of body). it should work fine for you.

Comment: @JeremyL as i said it is a timing issue on where your script is. `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` will also throw the error when it is wrapped in the head and not in window.onload or document.ready provided the timing. thats the theory and mostly i have seen that way practically.

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle is  working fine. But always enclose your Js code within document.onready function

```
$(function(){
< your Js code here >
});
```

This is because the code is read before the element is rendered by the browser, so while reading it cant bind to anything which is not even there.Thus your code may not work.

Comment: *Even in the fiddle, only the window and document binds were working

Answer (score 0):

By changing you `console.log` statements to `alert()` the window goes mad, they are all working. That is not your problem.